# no attribute is present in numerical to polynominal data transformation subset window in rapidminer?

Tags: typeconverter, rapidminer

when I try to convert some `numerical` attribute to `polynominal` using `numerical to polynominal convertor` and `filter by subset`, No attribute is shown on the left side of its window ?How should i overcome this issue?
thank you in advance

***Edit*** : input result

```
 Role   Name    Type    Range                   Missing
-       a     integer    = [?...?]; mean =?   no missing values
-       b     integer    = [?...?]; mean =?   no missing values
-       c    integer    = [?...?]; mean =?   no missing values  
-       d     Real    = [?...?]; mean =?   no missing values
```

Comment: It's difficult without seeing your data but I suspect your attributes are not numerical so they do not appear in the selection window. To check, set a breakpoint before the `Numerical to Polynominal` operator and look at the statistics for the example set.

Comment: @awchisholm, please see the input result.

Comment: Very odd. How many examples are in the example set and are there infinite values present in the data?

Comment: @awchisholm the data set are 629 rows and the attribute which it  identify its type as real is 15 digit number.

Comment: It's odd. The input result you showed has `?` which is a sign of a zero size example set although the `?...?` in the range is most odd - if these were infinite values I might understand. If there are 629 examples then I can't see how it happened. The only way forward is to post a representative process with data that shows the problem.

Comment: Thanks @awchisholm for your help, but I can't post the data publicly.